# how can we get content of inner tag of the same tag name in parse xml in android?

Tags: android, parsing, xml-parsing

how can we get content of inner tag of the same tag name  in parse xml in android ?
if a programme have same tag name in xml than how can we get the value of inner tag of that tag whose name is same every time i got only value related to first tag of that name
my local xml file is shown below.how can i pasre and get value?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<categories>
<category>
<id>
1
</id>
<name>
Main name
</name> 
<subcategories>
<count>
1
</count>
<subcategory>
<id>
2
</id>
<name>
Sub name
</name> 
<products> 
<count>
5
</count> 
<product> 
<id>
1
</id>
<name>
fullname
</name>
<description>
this is full name and something 
</description>
<color>
white
</color> 
<size>
xyz
</size>
<images> 
<count>
2
</count>
<image>
<title>
test
</title>
<url>
www.test.com/test1.jpg
</url> 
</image>
</images> 
</product>
</products>
</subcategory>
</subcategories>
</category>
<category> 
<id>
2
</id> 
<name>
other name
</name>
<subcategories>
<count>
1
</count>
<subcategory>
<id>
2
</id> 
<name>
other name subname
</name> 
<products>
<count>
5
</count> 
<product> 
<id>
1
</id>
<name>
patname of othername
</name>
<description>
this isapt name and something
</description>
<color>
white
</color> 
<size>
xyz
</size> 
<images>
<count>
2
</count> 
<image> 
<title>
test
</title>
<url>
www.test.com/test1.jpg
</url>
</image>
</images> 
</product>
</products> 
</subcategory>
</subcategories>
</category> 
</categories>
```

Comment: It depends on parser which parser u r using ?????????

Comment: You should also give an xml sample snippet… What have you tried?

Comment: i have add my local xml file in question so after seeing that give an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase you are using DOM parser you can simply check the parentMode as outer and inner node will have different parent nodes.